# Perform poisson regression for each value in column

Tags: r, poisson

I have a long-form dataframe that I am performing a poisson regression on.

```
 'data.frame':  20000 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ cal_y  : int  2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 ...
 $ age_y  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gender : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ cal_m  : int  9 7 8 1 6 11 2 10 3 4 ...
 $ n_outcome: int  276 187 164 352 229 250 332 267 348 291 ...
 $ n_atrisk : int  4645 4645 4645 4645 4645 4645 4645 4645 4645 4645 ...

glm(n_outcome ~ factor(cal_y) + factor(cal_m) + gender + offset(log(n_atrisk)),
data = df, family =poisson)
```

I would like to know the coefficients of the exposure cal_y for the outcome n_outcome for every age_y and preferably be able to aggregate this information into one df.

I have tried several misguided versions of lapply() and tapply(). Currently, my best solution is to do this by hand:

```
glm(n_outcome ~ factor(cal_y) + factor(cal_m) + gender + offset(log(n_atrisk)),
data = filter(df, age_y >= 0, age_y <1), family =poisson)
```

But this is both tedious (range(age_y) = 0 105), the results are not easily combined in a new df and I'm not sure it is statistically correct to subset the data prior to performing the regression.

Any pointers, comments or help is appreciated.

Comment: why exactly are you doing subset regressions vs a single regression?

Comment: @Alex I am trying to determine the effect of the exposure, in this case calendar year (cal_y), on a count outcome (n_outcome). I both have reason to believe that the effect will vary extensively depending on the age in years (age_y), and the degree of this variation is very interesting for my line of study. More accurately, I wish to know the relative risk for each age_y. If there is a better way I am very open to suggestions

Comment: Yes, but what is the reason for using **subsets**? IE- why don't you just include `age_y` as an independent variable?

Comment: @Alex If I include age_y as an independent variable the coefficient output describes the difference in n_outcome of age_y = (1, 2, 3, ... , 100) compared to age_y = 0. I would like to know the coefficient for the difference in n_outcome for cal_y for every age_y. In reality I will be aggregating age_y into age_brackets but I neglected to mention this in the question stem for simplicity.

Comment: @Alex is this a flawed way of thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with dplyr and my [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

results <- df %>%
  group_by(age_y) %>%
  do(tidy(glm(n_outcome ~ factor(cal_y) + factor(cal_m) + gender + offset(log(n_atrisk)),
              data = ., family =poisson)))
```

This works because `group_by` and `do` performs the regression for each `age_y` value, and then `tidy` turns each regression into a data frame that can be recombined.

See the [broom and dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) vignette for more.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe in the comments above is what happens if you use effects coding vs a means model. The two are equivalent and just represent different constraints placed on the parameters (leave one out vs sum to 0). But it appears to be skewing your thinking here. If you use `age_y` as a categorical coding you will get the appropriate output

By using subset-regression, you are not including all available information in each model, which is the statistically invalid approach. This also increases the type I error rate. You should use all available information in your model. Therefore, this is the correct specification:

```
# this is the default way that R handles things, leaving one level out.
glm(n_outcome ~ factor(age_y) + factor(cal_y) + factor(cal_m) + gender + offset(log(n_atrisk)),
data = df, family= poisson(link = "log"))

# In contrast, this will provide an estimate for each level of
# factor(age_y) where the test-statistic is if the coefficient
# is statistically different from zero.
glm(n_outcome ~ 0 + factor(age_y) + factor(cal_y) + factor(cal_m) + gender + offset(log(n_atrisk)),
data = df, family= poisson(link = "log"))
```

The above is correct unless you expect different effects for `cal_y`, `gender`, and/or `n_atrisk` by each `age_y` in which can you will need to get estimates of the interaction of these variables with `age_y` (which can still be specified in a single model).

If you wish to test if the levels of `age_y` are different from each other, you can test their contrasts.

That is, using `(... 0 + factor(age_y) ...)` -- which sounds like your preference -- gives you information on each level of `age_y` relative to the null hypothesis, but it does not provide a statistical test between say `age_y:level1 vs age_y:level2`. To do this test, you need to test their contrasts.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I see the wisdom in what you are saying and will spend the next couple of days reading up on effects coding vs. a means model. I do not pretend to understand what this means as of right now. However, testing the code you have given me, I am obviously using the incorrect type of coding as the output is as I described in my comment above, i.e. the coefficient output describes the change in n_outcome for age_y = (0, 1, ... , 100) compared to age_y = 0. With interaction it shows the same except also by factor(cal_y).

Comment: That is the default in **R**. If you use `glm(n_outcome ~ 0 + factor(age_y) ... )` the statistics reported for each level of `age_y` will be testing if the coefficient is statistically different from 0. Since I wasn't sure exactly what you were after, I didn't put that in my solution. I'll update it.